# How Launch service when application is closed or vice versa

Tags: android, service

I am stuck with a scenario in which i am having my application and a service. i need to 
start a service when my application is closed, and i need to stop my service when my application is running, in the service i will launch a thread which will  be fetching the location , i know that there are mutiple options to implement this scenario. but i am confused which one to use, should i use AIDL to implement, or to use extra bundle in the intent used to start the service,or do i have to bind to service from my activity , or use simple boolean variable making it true and false depending on application is started or closed. 
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: AIDL will be too much for your requirement. Why don't you use simple onStart() and onStop() methods, this would be the simplest way to handle that.